# Switch virtual interface

Tags: vlan, subnet, network

Single SVI can be mapped to a VLAN. When configuring VLAN on SVI, are there any fix no of subnets can be assigned to a single VLAN?

maximum number of VLANs can be configured on the switch =4094

since, number of subnets can assigned to a VLAN here =1 (on SVI)

is that correct?

Comment: What's the switch model and software version? Usually, the SVI details depend on the hardware at hand.

Comment: Cisco Catalyst 3560

Comment: "_Single SVI can be mapped to a VLAN._" That is odd phrasing and an awkward way to look at it. An SVI is the virtual interface created on a particular VLAN. Notice the way the SVI is created: `interface Vlan<vlan number>`. The SVI is an interface for exactly one VLAN, which is the VLAN in the interface name.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify an unlimited amount of secondary IP addresses to a VLAN/SVI and physical interface on routers and layer 3 switches.

However, let's assume you create 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24 on a single **interface** on a router/layer 3 switch, then both subnets will be in the same vlan and broadcast domain. For instance, if host 192.168.1.5 sends a broadcast, all hosts in both 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24 will receive it.

Under an interface, you can keep adding the command:

```
(config-if)# ip address ip-address subnet-mask secondary
```

Remember that you can't create overlapping IP addresses/subnets.

Caveat: It's required on layer 3 switches, that the IOS is at least IP services or similar for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Catalyst 3560 Software Configuration Guide, Release 12.2(52)SE](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/12-2_52_se/configuration/guide/3560scg/swint.html):

> A switch virtual interface (SVI) represents a VLAN of switch ports as
>   one interface to the routing or bridging function in the system.
>   **Only one SVI can be associated with a VLAN**, but you need to configure an SVI for a VLAN only when you wish to route between VLANs,
>   to fallback-bridge nonroutable protocols between VLANs, or to provide
>   IP host connectivity to the switch.

The answer is **one**.

4094 is the number of valid VLAN IDs. The switch can be configured with a total of 1005 VLANs.

Comment: I meant that, how many subnets can be assigned to a single VLAN , under SVI configuration.

Comment: According to the same guide, you can only configure a single IP address on an SVI.